# Apply cwt in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gaussian, wavelet, differentiation

I'm trying to implement an algorithm which has been described in a paper. It deals with accelerometer data which has to be filtered and differentiated. My input is a vector (1 column, multiple rows).

[As described here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKxoI.png)

The vector has to differentiated using a Gaussian CWT with the MatLab function *cwt*. Scale has to be 'scale10' and wavelet 'gaus1'.

When I try to implement the instructions in MatLab, I type the following:

```
    dudx=cwt(vector,'scale10','gaus1');
```

This is the error I get:

```
    Undefined function 'sqrt' for input arguments of type 'char'.

    Error in cwt (line 278)
    coefs(ind,:) = -sqrt(a)*wkeep1(diff(wconv1(ySIG,f)),lenSIG);
```

As it should actually work with the input, I've really no idea what I could change. I also went through the mathworks pages from *cwt* and *wavefun* but without any solution.

I've never before used a CWT, therefore I thought that I may misunderstood something and applied the instructions wrong. Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the function right.  The second parameter is a vector of scales where each number is the desired scale you want.  `scale10` doesn't mean anything.  Do you want the **10th** scale?

Do this:

```
dudx=cwt(vector,10,'gaus1');
```

Please read the documentation here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/cwt.html